# How to raise PropertyChanged event on lazy loaded properties

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading, inotifypropertychanged

so i have a simple relation between an entity and a complex type, and i want to notify the entity when the complex type changes,as in this code

```
[Table("Bills")]
public class Bill : NotifyBase
{
    //how to call SetWithNotif when this changes ?
    public virtual Discount Discount { get; set; }

}

[ComplexType]
public class Discount : NotifyBase
{
   //some props in here  
}

 public class NotifyBase : INotifyPropertyChanged,INotifyPropertyChanging
 {       
    public void SetWithNotif<T>(T val,ref T field,[CallerMemberName] string prop = "" )
    {
        if (!field.Equals(val))
        {
            PropertyChanging?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(prop));
            field = val;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
    [field: NotMapped]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    [field: NotMapped]
    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh i just realised that `virtual` means that it can have a body, and luckily `EntityFramework` calls that body after it finishes lazy loading, so this worked perfectly

```
[Table("Bills")]
public class Bill : NotifyBase
{
    //works !!
    private Discount m_Discount;
    public virtual Discount Discount
    {
        get { return m_Discount; }
        set { SetWithNotif(value, ref m_Discount); }
    }


}

[ComplexType]
public class Discount : NotifyBase
{
   //some props in here  
}

 public class NotifyBase : INotifyPropertyChanged,INotifyPropertyChanging
 {       
    public void SetWithNotif<T>(T val,ref T field,[CallerMemberName] string prop = "" )
    {
        if (!field.Equals(val))
        {
            PropertyChanging?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(prop));
            field = val;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
    [field: NotMapped]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    [field: NotMapped]
    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;
}
```